# Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390 camera problem

Tags: dell, 19.10, camera

I have been able to install ubuntu 19.10 on my new Dell XPS 7390 2-in-1 without major problems. The only problem is that camera is not working, I have tried with cheese and hangouts but camera is not even detected. I have 5.3.0-23-generic kernel version. is there someone who knows how to fix that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell/XPS/XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:

> Intel Icelake integrated the IPU 4th Generation Gen IPU with on-die
>   MIPI interface, which is not supported by Linux.

Basically the camera doesn't work right now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer kyt. It's a pity I can't do anything by now.

Comment: I feel the same way. Also waiting for a fix to come along.